# Инициация запроса сервером

Tags: php, javascript

Может ли сервер инициировать запрос к пользователю?
Т.е. если у пользователя открыта страница, сервер может это увидеть и что-нибудь ему послать?

...вопрос встал давно, в те времена, когда программировать еще толком не умел и мне поставили задачу написать чат. Сразу подумал не о том, чтобы клиент по заданому интервалу отправлял запросы и получал новые сообщения, а о том, чтобы при новом сообщении сервер рассылал его всем подключенным пользователям.

Comment: А если реализовать через ajax?

Comment: В принципе можно, но это уже не HTTP

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите тут: [COMET](http://javascript.ru/ajax/comet).
Описано множество вариантов, с помощью которых можно правильно осуществить вашу задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна поддержка старых браузеров, то смотрите в сторону СОМЕТ или Flash p2p. Но с приходом HTML5 появился протокол WebSocket, предназначенный для обмена сообщениями между браузером и веб-сервером в режиме реального времени.